# What is "ejecting"

Tags: vue-cli

The vue cli documentaion mention it in:

> At the same time, it still offers the flexibility to tweak the config
> of each tool without the need for **ejecting**

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

"ejecting", popularized by Create-React-App, means to stop using a tool that automatically creates and maintains your code or configuration, so you can instead maintain this by hand.

The typical scenario is that you start using a tool to simplify the creation and development of a small project. However, as the project becomes more complex, the tool no longer supports everything you need to do.

When the tool supports automatic ejecting, it will hard-code its currently generated files into the project, and remove any hooks that would regenerate them. The project should still work the same way, but you can now make advanced customizations to the code/config without them being overwritten, at the cost of losing the convenience of the tool.